# Trouble Understanding Error Message (Regression in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I am currently following sentdex's YouTube tutorial for Practical Machine Learning (ep. 3 by the way). I have encountered an error message that I don't understand when I try to print a table. The following is my code, and its error message.

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import math

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df = df[['Adj.Open', 'Adj.High', 'Adj.Low', 'Adj.Close', 'Adj.Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj.High'] - df['Adj.Close'])/ df['Adj.Close'] * 
 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj.Close'] - df['Adj.Open'])/ df['Adj.Open'] * 
100.0

df = df[['Adj.Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj.Volume']]


forecastcol = 'Adj. Close'
df. fillna(-99999, inplace=True)

forecast_out = int (math.ceil (0.1 * len(df)))

df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

print(df.head())
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\progr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\regression.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
  File "C:\Users\progr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\get.py", line 48, in get
    data = Dataset(dataset_args['code']).data(params=kwargs, handle_column_not_found=True)
  File "C:\Users\progr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\dataset.py", line 47, in data
    return Data.all(**updated_options)
  File "C:\Users\progr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\operations\list.py", line 15, in all
    r = Connection.request('get', path, **options)
  File "C:\Users\progr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 38, in request
    return cls.execute_request(http_verb, abs_url, **options)
  File "C:\Users\progr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 50, in execute_request
    cls.handle_api_error(response)
  File "C:\Users\progr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 114, in handle_api_error
    raise klass(message, resp.status_code, resp.text, resp.headers, code)`

I expected the output to be a table of values, with labeled headers as 'Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', and etc.

Comment: Quandl has nice documentation for python. Read the docs of the method ```quandl.get``` first: https://www.quandl.com/tools/python  Also make sure your are using a valid API key

Comment: The problem is in your first line, not the calculations you do.